# Getting index.php instead single.php for displaying posts

Tags: posts

I'm (locally) building a custom theme.

So far I have:

- index.php
- single.php
- page.php
- custom page template called about-page.php
- two different headers: one for default use and one for the single.php

NO functions.php;
NO custom taxonomy;
Permalink settings > Common settings : default

My index.php has a list of posts (all of those belonging to a specified category), when I click on one of those posts I end to the index.php BUT with the right custom header (header I created for the posts, it's called header-single.php).

**So, I'm getting the index.php istead of the single.php**

I read around other people had the same problem with the word "year" or some other Reserved Terms. I don't think it's my case.

In my home page I have:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Front Page Template
 */
get_header(); ?>
<nav id="menu">
        <ul class="postlist">
            <?php
                $lastposts = get_posts('numberposts=20&orderby=date&cat=9');
                foreach($lastposts as $post) :
                setup_postdata($post);
                ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a</li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
</nav>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

EDIT

Here's the structure of my single.php

```
<?php
/*
 Template Name: Single project
  */
get_header(); ?>

<div id="flex-container">   
//something
</div>

<div id="read">
    <a>READ</a>
</div>
<div id="read_slider">
    <div id="read_close">
        <a>CLOSE</a>
    </div>

    <div id="read_text">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>  
</div>

</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What is the structure in your single.php template?

Comment: Edited the question with my single.php structure. Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the Template Name of your single.php. I'm not sure about this, but I think this could be confusing to the template structure.

Comment: have you disabled all plugins? output the query object in your `index.php` file to see what the main query vars look like, this is how WordPress decides what template to load. The contents of your single template are completely irrelevant, despite what others suggest here. Add `var_dump($wp_query);` somewhere in the template, then edit your question and add that output.

Answer (score 1):

Your structures is completely wrong. Remove the template name from your `index.php` and `single.php` templates. You only should use those if you create a custom `page.php` template to let wordpress know it is a custom page. This should apply to your `about-page.php`, which is also wrongly named, it should be `page-about.php`. Your `index.php` looks about right, but your `single.php` is bit of a mess, that is why wordpress skip that template completely and uses `index.php` instead.

There is no loop defined in your `single.php`. The loop looks something like this:

```
// Start the Loop.
while ( have_posts() ) { 
    the_post(); 

    //Content of the loop goes here, in your case 
    the_content();

}
```

Go and have a look at the default themes in the Wordpress core and see how their templates are put together and how your structures should look like. Working from those themes will guide you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advices but nothing is working.

My `single.php` is now literally:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_content();
            endwhile;
        ?> 
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with neither the `single-CUSTOM-TYPE.php` nor the `single.php` being rendered after clicking the single-post-link.... only `index.php` instead of the correct file...

What helped me was a simple change back to Standard Permalinks in *"Settings" -> "Permalinks"* and a restore back to "Name of the Post" (Beitragsname)....

Maybe this might help someone else as well